# H5diff exclude uninteresting part

Tags: hdf5

If i check for differences in `h5` files with

```
h5diff -r file1.h5 file2.h5
```

I get a ton of not interesting 0 differences like

```
0 differences found
dataset: </BDEAD_PY> and </BDEAD_PY>
0 differences found
dataset: </BLEAF> and </BLEAF>
0 differences found  ...
```

Can I exclude this output?

Answer (score 0):

If you leave off the `-r` `h5diff` will only report differences.

Comment: `h5diff -r file{1,2}.h5 | grep -v "0 differences"`?